# Bootstrap card alignment is not proper

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a rails application with Bootstrap 4. There is some styling issue with the `card` of Bootstrap that I can't figure out.

**Original**
[image]

**After Pressing the Button**

[image]

I don't know why the margins all moved around.

```
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <!-- Taken directly from bootstrap -->
    <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-header">Header</div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
<%end %>


<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <%= f.label :title, class:"col-sm-2 col-form-label" %>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <%= f.text_field :title, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Title of Article" %>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <%= f.label :description, class:"col-sm-2 col-form-label" %>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <%= f.text_area :description, class:"form-control", placeholder:"Body of Article", rows:10 %>
        </div>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-2">
      <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="text-center">
    [ <%= link_to "Cancel request and return to articles listing", articles_path %> ]
</div>
    <%# </div>
</div> %>
```

There is no external css that affects this page. This page is rendered from my partial:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="width: 75%;margin-top: 100px;">

    <h1 class="text-center"> Create an article </h1>

    <%= render 'form'%>

</div>
```

When I enter the card manually from Chrome Developer tools, it gives me what I want

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

`<%= f.label :title, class:"col-sm-2 col-form-label" %>`

to

```
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <%= f.label :title, class:"col-form-label" %>
        </div>
```